# SnowSQL to Select Day & Time Separately

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Source is THREE columns, where third column (HOURS) is of type VARCHAR and it has CSV values:

```
Monday, 10:30AM–12AM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–12AM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM
```

Desired output in 4 columns, where HOURS will be translated to DAY and SCHEDULE columns.

| ID | VENDOR | DAY | SCHEDULE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | ABC | Monday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Tuesday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Wednesday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Thursday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Friday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Saturday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Sunday | 10:30AM–12AM |

So 1 ID, VENDOR with 1 HOUR needs to be translated to 7 rows

Here is sample table with sample records:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER, VENDOR VARCHAR2, HOURS VARCHAR2);

INSERT INTO t1 (id, vendor, hours)
VALUES 
(1001, 'ABC', 'Monday, 07:00AM–12AM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–12AM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
(1002, 'DEF', 'Monday, 08:00AM–01PM, Tuesday, 08:00AM–01PM, Wednesday, 08:00AM–01PM, Thursday, 08:00AM–01PM, Friday, 08:00AM–01PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–01PM'),
(1003, 'GHE', 'Monday, 09:00AM–02PM, Tuesday, 09:00AM–02PM, Wednesday, 09:00AM–02PM, Thursday, 09:00AM–02PM, Friday, 09:00AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
(1004, 'IJK', 'Monday, 10:00AM–03PM, Tuesday, 10:00AM–03PM, Wednesday, 10:00AM–03PM, Thursday, 10:00AM–03PM, Friday, 10:00AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
(1005, 'LMN', 'Monday, 10:30AM–04PM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah a fun one, tweak the input to only have one comma per day/hour, then split_to_table and then split by the tweak for quick wins, fun!

so with you great sample data turned into a CTE:

```
WITH cte_table_data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1001, 'ABC', 'Monday, 07:00AM–12AM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–12AM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
        (1002, 'DEF', 'Monday, 08:00AM–01PM, Tuesday, 08:00AM–01PM, Wednesday, 08:00AM–01PM, Thursday, 08:00AM–01PM, Friday, 08:00AM–01PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–01PM'),
        (1003, 'GHE', 'Monday, 09:00AM–02PM, Tuesday, 09:00AM–02PM, Wednesday, 09:00AM–02PM, Thursday, 09:00AM–02PM, Friday, 09:00AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
        (1004, 'IJK', 'Monday, 10:00AM–03PM, Tuesday, 10:00AM–03PM, Wednesday, 10:00AM–03PM, Thursday, 10:00AM–03PM, Friday, 10:00AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
        (1005, 'LMN', 'Monday, 10:30AM–04PM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM')
    t(id, vendor, hours)
)
```

and this SQL

```
select 
    c.id, 
    c.vendor,
    trim(split_part(v.value,'|',1)) as day,
    trim(split_part(v.value,'|',2)) as SCHEDULE
from cte_table_data as c
    ,table(split_to_table(replace(c.hours,'y,','y|'), ',')) v
order by v.seq, v.index;
```

| ID | VENDOR | DAY | SCHEDULE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | ABC | Monday | 07:00AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Tuesday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Wednesday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Thursday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Friday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Saturday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1001 | ABC | Sunday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1002 | DEF | Monday | 08:00AM–01PM |
| 1002 | DEF | Tuesday | 08:00AM–01PM |
| 1002 | DEF | Wednesday | 08:00AM–01PM |
| 1002 | DEF | Thursday | 08:00AM–01PM |
| 1002 | DEF | Friday | 08:00AM–01PM |
| 1002 | DEF | Saturday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1002 | DEF | Sunday | 10:30AM–01PM |
| 1003 | GHE | Monday | 09:00AM–02PM |
| 1003 | GHE | Tuesday | 09:00AM–02PM |
| 1003 | GHE | Wednesday | 09:00AM–02PM |
| 1003 | GHE | Thursday | 09:00AM–02PM |
| 1003 | GHE | Friday | 09:00AM–02PM |
| 1003 | GHE | Saturday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1003 | GHE | Sunday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1004 | IJK | Monday | 10:00AM–03PM |
| 1004 | IJK | Tuesday | 10:00AM–03PM |
| 1004 | IJK | Wednesday | 10:00AM–03PM |
| 1004 | IJK | Thursday | 10:00AM–03PM |
| 1004 | IJK | Friday | 10:00AM–02PM |
| 1004 | IJK | Saturday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1004 | IJK | Sunday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1005 | LMN | Monday | 10:30AM–04PM |
| 1005 | LMN | Tuesday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1005 | LMN | Wednesday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1005 | LMN | Thursday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1005 | LMN | Friday | 10:30AM–02PM |
| 1005 | LMN | Saturday | 10:30AM–12AM |
| 1005 | LMN | Sunday | 10:30AM–12AM |

Comment: Thanks Simeon for your help

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE DEV.EDW.t1 (id NUMBER, VENDOR VARCHAR2, HOURS VARCHAR2);

INSERT INTO DEV.EDW.t1 (id, vendor, hours)
VALUES 
(1001, 'ABC', 'Monday, 07:00AM–12AM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–12AM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
(1002, 'DEF', 'Monday, 08:00AM–01PM, Tuesday, 08:00AM–01PM, Wednesday, 08:00AM–01PM, Thursday, 08:00AM–01PM, Friday, 08:00AM–01PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–01PM'),
(1003, 'GHE', 'Monday, 09:00AM–02PM, Tuesday, 09:00AM–02PM, Wednesday, 09:00AM–02PM, Thursday, 09:00AM–02PM, Friday, 09:00AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
(1004, 'IJK', 'Monday, 10:00AM–03PM, Tuesday, 10:00AM–03PM, Wednesday, 10:00AM–03PM, Thursday, 10:00AM–03PM, Friday, 10:00AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM'),
(1005, 'LMN', 'Monday, 10:30AM–04PM, Tuesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Wednesday, 10:30AM–12AM, Thursday, 10:30AM–12AM, Friday, 10:30AM–02PM, Saturday, 10:30AM–12AM, Sunday, 10:30AM–12AM');

SELECT * FROM DEV.EDW.t1;

SELECT Id,Vendor,DAY,SCHEDULE FROM (
Select  src.id,src.Vendor
       ,CASE WHEN Index%2=1 THEN VALUE END AS DAY
       ,LEAD(VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY SEQ ORDER BY INDEX) AS SCHEDULE
From (SELECT ID,VENDOR,HOURS FROM DEV.EDW.t1 ) src, table(strtok_split_to_table(src.HOURS,','))
) out WHERE DAY IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID,Vendor
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I apologies for incomplete informations. Values in the column will be dynamic. I added sample table and records in the description now.

Comment: @LazyDeveloper Hey, I just replaced the manual input with the table input and is working fine on dynamic values provided pattern (Day, Hours) remains the same. Kindly check. thanks

Comment: Thanks Anshul for your help

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH days_of_week AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY1) AS row_number
    FROM VALUES
        ('Monday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Tuesday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Wednesday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Thursday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Friday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Saturday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Sunday'), ('10:30AM–12AM')
    )
  WHERE row_number % 2 = 1 ),
hours_open AS (
  SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY1) AS row_number
    FROM VALUES
        ('Monday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Tuesday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Wednesday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Thursday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Friday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Saturday'), ('10:30AM–12AM'), ('Sunday'), ('10:30AM–12AM')
    )
  WHERE row_number % 2 = 0)
SELECT  d.column1 AS Day, h.column1 AS Schedule 
FROM days_of_week d
INNER JOIN hours_open h
ON d.row_number = h.row_number-1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I apologies for incomplete informations. Values in the column will be dynamic. I added sample table and records in the description now.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule