# Find Working days based on Weekly or Monthly Schedule

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any help is greatly appreciated in following question.
I have weekly or monthly schedule of shop but shop may be open certain days of the week instead of whole week. So i need to calculate working days of shop.

Week starts from Sunday.

[image]

[image]
In the above example, shop 1001 has weekly schedule.
we need to calculate it period of consecutive working days.
first schedule is Tuesday-Thursday (3 days)
second schedule is Saturday (1 day)

Sample data for required SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE fact_shop_schedule (
      shop_id varchar ,
      shop_start_time timestamp ,
      shop_end_time timestamp ,
      schedule_start_time varchar ,
      schedule_end_time varchar
    );
```

```
    INSERT INTO fact_shop_schedule (shop_id, shop_start_time, shop_end_time, schedule_start_time, schedule_end_time)
    VALUES 
    (1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'TUESDAY 00:00',   'TUESDAY 23:59'),
    (1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'WEDNESDAY 00:00', 'WEDNESDAY 23:59'),
    (1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'THURSDAY 00:00',  'THURSDAY 23:59'),
    (1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'SATURDAY 00:00',  'SATURDAY 23:59'),
    (1002, '2022-04-01 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'MONDAY 00:00',    'MONDAY 23:59'),
    (1002, '2022-04-01 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'TUESDAY 00:00',   'TUESDAY 23:59'),
    (1002, '2022-04-01 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'WEDNESDAY 00:00', 'WEDNESDAY 23:59'),
    (1002, '2022-04-01 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'FRIDAY 00:00',    'FRIDAY 23:59'),
    (1002, '2022-04-01 07:00:00.000000000'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00.000000000'::timestamp, 'SATURDAY 00:00',  'SATURDAY 23:59')
    ;
```

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE dim_dates (
      day            varchar ,
      day_name       varchar ,
      day_short_name varchar ,
      day_of_month   varchar ,
      day_of_week    integer ,
      start_of_week  date    ,
      end_of_week    date    ,
      month          date
    );
```

```
    INSERT INTO dim_dates (day, day_name, day_short_name, day_of_month, day_of_week, start_of_week, end_of_week, month)
    VALUES 
    ('2022-04-01', 'Friday',    'Fri', 08, 5, '2022-03-28', '2022-04-03', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-02', 'Saturday',  'Sat', 09, 6, '2022-03-28', '2022-04-03', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-03', 'Sunday',    'Sun', 03, 0, '2022-03-28', '2022-04-03', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-04', 'Monday',    'Mon', 04, 1, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-05', 'Tuesday',   'Tue', 05, 2, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-06', 'Wednesday', 'Wed', 06, 3, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-07', 'Thursday',  'Thu', 07, 4, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-08', 'Friday',    'Fri', 08, 5, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-09', 'Saturday',  'Sat', 09, 6, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-10', 'Sunday',    'Sun', 10, 0, '2022-04-04', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-11', 'Monday',    'Mon', 11, 1, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-12', 'Tuesday',   'Tue', 12, 2, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-13', 'Wednesday', 'Wed', 13, 3, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-14', 'Thursday',  'Thu', 14, 4, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-15', 'Friday',    'Fri', 15, 5, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-17', 'Saturday',  'Sat', 16, 6, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-17', 'Sunday',    'Sun', 17, 0, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-18', 'Monday',    'Mon', 18, 1, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-19', 'Tuesday',   'Tue', 19, 2, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-20', 'Wednesday', 'Wed', 20, 3, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-21', 'Thursday',  'Thu', 21, 4, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-22', 'Friday',    'Fri', 22, 5, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-23', 'Saturday',  'Sat', 33, 6, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-24', 'Sunday',    'Sun', 24, 0, '2022-04-18', '2022-04-24', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-25', 'Monday',    'Mon', 25, 1, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-26', 'Tuesday',   'Tue', 26, 2, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-27', 'Wednesday', 'Wed', 26, 3, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-28', 'Thursday',  'Thu', 28, 4, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-29', 'Friday',    'Fri', 29, 5, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-04-30', 'Saturday',  'Sat', 30, 6, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-01'),
    ('2022-05-01', 'Sunday',    'Sun', 1,  0, '2022-04-25', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01'),
    ('2022-05-02', 'Monday',    'Mon', 2,  1, '2022-05-02', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-01'),
    ('2022-05-03', 'Tuesday',   'Tue', 3,  2, '2022-05-02', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-01')
    ;
```

Comment: Please update the question with what you've tried and where it's not working.

Comment: Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: What have you tried - or are you literally stuck and don't know how to approach this problem?

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate lag of consective days to get time period (specially. for month period).

Here is what I have so far:

Comment: SELECT  
 , regexp_substr(t2.schedule_start_time, '^[^, ]*') AS placement_start_day
 , regexp_substr(t2.schedule_end_time, '^[^, ]*')   AS placement_end_day
 , dd.day_of_week
 , dd.week 
 , dd.last_day_of_week
 , UPPER(coalesce(dd.day_name,'Sunday')) AS day_name
FROM fact_shop_schedule t2
INNER JOIN dimension_date dd ON t2.shop_start_time::date >= dd.week::date AND t2.shop_start_time::date <= dd.last_day_of_week::date
  AND regexp_substr(t2.schedule_start_time, '^[^, ]*') = UPPER(coalesce(dd.day_name,'Sunday'))
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY dd.week, day_of_week;

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time and got it, thanks everyone for your suggestions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_source
AS
SELECT  
   t2.shop_id                                        AS shop_id 
 , t2.shop_start_time                                AS start_time
 , t2.shop_end_time                                  AS end_time
 , t2.schedule_start_time                            AS schedule_start_time
 , t2.schedule_end_time                              AS schedule_end_time
 , regexp_substr(t2.schedule_start_time, '^[^, ]*')  AS schedule_start_day
 , regexp_substr(t2.schedule_end_time, '^[^, ]*')    AS schedule_end_day
 , dd.day                                            AS day
 , UPPER(coalesce(dd.day_name,'Sunday'))             AS day_name
FROM fact_shop_schedule t2
INNER JOIN dim_dates dd ON dd.day BETWEEN t2.shop_start_time::date AND t2.shop_end_time::date
--INNER JOIN dimension_date dd ON t2.shop_start_time::date >= dd.week::date AND t2.shop_start_time::date <= dd.last_day_of_week::date
  AND regexp_substr(t2.schedule_start_time, '^[^, ]*') = UPPER(coalesce(dd.day_name,'Sunday'))
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY shop_id, day;


CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_grouping_set
AS
SELECT  
   shop_id
 , day
 , start_time
 , end_time
 , schedule_start_time
 , schedule_end_time
 , schedule_start_day
 , schedule_end_day
 , DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY shop_id ORDER BY day), day) AS GroupingSet
FROM temp_source;


SELECT
   shop_id      AS shop_id
 , MIN(day)     AS start_date
 , MAX(day)     AS end_date
 , CASE 
    WHEN end_date>start_date THEN datediff(day,start_date,end_date)+1
    WHEN end_date=start_date THEN 1
   END AS working_days  
FROM temp_grouping_set
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY shop_id, GroupingSet
ORDER BY shop_id, start_date;
```