# Get Period normalized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any help is greatly appreciated in following question. I have weekly schedule of shop but shop may be open certain days of the week instead of whole week. So i need to calculate working days of shop.

Week starts from Sunday.
[image]

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE fact_shop_schedule (
  shop_id varchar ,
  shop_start_time timestamp ,
  shop_end_time timestamp ,
  schedule_start_time varchar ,
  schedule_end_time varchar ,
  day_of_week number
);
INSERT INTO fact_shop_schedule (shop_id, shop_start_time, shop_end_time, schedule_start_time, schedule_end_time, day_of_week)
VALUES 
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'MONDAY 00:00',    'MONDAY 23:59', 1),
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'TUESDAY 00:00',   'TUESDAY 23:59', 2),
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'WEDNESDAY 00:00', 'WEDNESDAY 23:59', 3),
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'THURSDAY 00:00',  'THURSDAY 23:59', 4),
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'FRIDAY 00:00',  'FRIDAY 23:59', 5),
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'SATURDAY 00:00',  'SATURDAY 23:59', 6),
(1000, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'SUNDAY 00:00',  'SUNDAY 23:59', 7),

(1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'TUESDAY 00:00',   'TUESDAY 23:59', 2),
(1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'WEDNESDAY 00:00', 'WEDNESDAY 23:59', 3),
(1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'THURSDAY 00:00',  'THURSDAY 23:59', 4),
(1001, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'SATURDAY 00:00',  'SATURDAY 23:59', 6),

(1002, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'MONDAY 00:00',    'MONDAY 23:59', 1),
(1002, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'TUESDAY 00:00',   'TUESDAY 23:59', 2),
(1002, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'WEDNESDAY 00:00', 'WEDNESDAY 23:59', 3),
(1002, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'FRIDAY 00:00',    'FRIDAY 23:59', 5),
(1002, '2022-04-26 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-01 06:59:00'::timestamp, 'SATURDAY 00:00',  'SATURDAY 23:59', 6)
;
```

Comment: [Find Working days based on Weekly or Monthly Schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule)?

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions, it doesn’t help you get an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Working days based on Weekly or Monthly Schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule)

Comment: There is no solution available there so I simplified question for now (to get to solution by breaking into smaller sets). 
Thanks

Comment: it's nice to see you break the questions up, because to be honest, when you paste your weeks work here and ask us to do it for you, with the inflammatory name that you have chosen, the desire to do you job for you is rather low.

Comment: Thanks for your honest feedback Simon, I might have to rename by display name now :)
I spent some time on it and got this part of it.
Thanks for your support, I might need it for next part of problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_source
AS
SELECT  
   t2.shop_id                                        AS shop_id 
 , t2.shop_start_time                                AS start_time
 , t2.shop_end_time                                  AS end_time
 , t2.schedule_start_time                            AS schedule_start_time
 , t2.schedule_end_time                              AS schedule_end_time
 , regexp_substr(t2.schedule_start_time, '^[^, ]*')  AS schedule_start_day
 , regexp_substr(t2.schedule_end_time, '^[^, ]*')    AS schedule_end_day
 , dd.day                                            AS day
 , UPPER(coalesce(dd.day_name,'Sunday'))             AS day_name
 , dd.day_of_week                                    AS day_of_week
 , dd.week                                           AS week 
 , dd.last_day_of_week                               AS last_day_of_week
 , dd.last_day_of_month                              AS last_day_of_month
FROM fact_shop_schedule t2
INNER JOIN dimension_date dd ON t2.shop_start_time::date >= dd.week::date AND t2.shop_start_time::date <= dd.last_day_of_week::date
  AND regexp_substr(t2.schedule_start_time, '^[^, ]*') = UPPER(coalesce(dd.day_name,'Sunday'))
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY dd.week, day_of_week;


CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_cte 
AS
SELECT  
   shop_id
 , day
 , start_time
 , end_time
 , schedule_start_time
 , schedule_end_time
 , schedule_start_day
 , schedule_end_day
 , DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY shop_id ORDER BY day), day) AS GroupingSet
FROM temp_source;


SELECT
   shop_id      AS shop_id
 , MIN(day)     AS start_date
 , MAX(day)     AS end_date
 , CASE 
    WHEN end_date>start_date THEN datediff(day,start_date,end_date)+1
    WHEN end_date=start_date THEN 1
   END AS working_days  
FROM    temp_cte
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY shop_id, GroupingSet
ORDER BY shop_id, start_date;
```

Comment: FYI, a temp table and a cte are conceptually similar but it doesn't make sense to put "cte" in your table names.

Comment: Agreed.
I should have used proper names for TEMP tables.

Comment: it is good that you manage to solve your own problem, just keep un at it and You'll soon have to rename :)